# Как разместить символ "вверху" строки?

Tags: html, css

Вот пример того, что мне нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример того, что у меня получается:

```css
.number {
  background: blue;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.dollar {
  background: blue;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.text {
  background: blue;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text_wrapper">
  <span class="dollar">$</span>
  <span class="number">50</span>
  <span class="text">per month</span>
</div>
```

Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтоб верхняя граница $ была на одном уровне с верхней границей 50? Как это отрегулировать, не прибегая к точным пиксельным значениям для свойства `line-height`?

Comment: Тег <sup>$</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

способ 1:
использовать тег `sup` и немного его скорректировать

```css
div {
  position:   relative;
  font-size: 42px;
}

sup {
  position:   relative;
  top:        2px;
  font-size:  22px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div><sup>$</sup>50</div>
```

Comment: Для данных тегов, стили лучше задавать в относительных единицах `em` или `%`.

Comment: согласен, но я просто продемонстрировал возможность, кроме того можно вообще описать свойства некоторого класс и его дочерних элементов и вообще не использовать `sup` и т.п.